# Python Multiple Function Scoping

Tags: python, function, if-statement

I am very new to python and have been reading up on python scoping however i am struggling with using values from a previous function e.g. in this case how do i get the randomly generated home and away goals to be used in the second function?. Please bare in mind i have only just began learning python so my code will not be the best attempt at all. Any help would be greatly appreciated as i could not find any threads relevant to my situation, thanks.

```
class One():

    def Team(home_goals,away_goals):

        home_goals = ()
        away_goals = ()        

        home_goals = round(random.uniform(0,10.0)

        return home_goals

        away_goals = round(random.uniform(0.1,10.0)

        return away_goals 



    def winner(home_goals,away_goals):

        if home_goals > away_goals
              winner = ("home")

        elif home_goals == away goals 
              winner = ("draw")

        else:
              winner = ("away")

        print(winner)

        return winner
```

Comment: everything should be indented once after the class i made an error when typing on here.

Comment: Does the indentation look correct now?

Comment: In python if you want to return two things, you use `return a, b` not two return statements.

Comment: yes thank you, do you have any idea on how i can take the values from the previous function to the second?

Answer (score 1):

Just pass the result of the first function to the second function:

```
def score():
    home_goals = 2
    away_goals = 3
    return home_goals, away_goals

def winner(home, away):
    # stuff ...
    pass

home, away = score()
winning_team = winner(home, away)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking for straight up functions, Bi Rico has the right answer.  However, you mention scoping and your code looks like it's trying to be a class.  So let's build a proper class.

Within the class functions are referred to as methods.  This is kind of a fancy way of saying "the scope of those functions are INSIDE the class 'One'

```py
import random

class One(object):
    home_goals = ()
    away_goals = ()

    def playGame(self):  
        self.home_goals = round(random.uniform(0,10.0))
        self.away_goals = round(random.uniform(0.1,10.0))
        return self.home_goals, self.away_goals 


    def determineWinner(self):
        if not self.home_goals or not self.away_goals:
            print("Teams must play game first!")
            return None
        if self.home_goals > self.away_goals:
            winner = ("home")
        elif self.home_goals == self.away_goals: 
            winner = ("draw")
        else:
            winner = ("away")
        print(winner)
        return winner

## usage 
one_obj = One() #create instance of One()
home, away = one_obj.playGame() 
game1 = one_obj.determineWinner()

one_obj.playGame() #play a new game
game2 = one_obj.determineWinner()
```

Classes have a special variable called 'self' which is the way the object `one_obj` shares the variable `home_goals` and `away_goals` between the two methods.

If we didn't use self, we would need to save the output from one method and pass them into the other.

You can do this with a decorator called `@staticmethod`

```py
import random
# still using a class but without self

class Two(object):
    @staticmethod
    def playGame():
        home_goals = round(random.uniform(0, 10.0))
        away_goals = round(random.uniform(0.1, 10.0))
        return home_goals, away_goals

    @staticmethod
    def determineWinner(home_goals, away_goals):
        if not home_goals or not away_goals:
            print("Teams must play game first!")
            return None
        if home_goals > away_goals:
            winner = ("home")
        elif home_goals == away_goals:
            winner = ("draw")
        else:
            winner = ("away")
        print(winner)
        return winner

two_obj = Two()

home, away = two_obj.playGame()
game1 = two_obj.determineWinner(home, away)
```

The point of a class is essentially bypassed as just a object to hold two functions. But in the context of your question, you MUST reference the instance `two_obj` in order to call those methods.

In Bi Rico's example, the functions are in the GLOBAL scope.  In the above examples, the methods (aka function in a class) are within the scope of the class.

It's possible to reference static methods without instantiating the class `Two()`:

```
home, away = Two.playGame()
game1 = Two.determineWinner(home, away)
```

Comment: Glad to help.  I highly recommend getting PyCharm for the code inspection.  It helped me a ton when I was first learning the language.  It pointed out mistakes I was making in the code.